# AutoIt + Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, autoit

Раньше создал тесты на java с помощью autoIt, для проверки работы программы(GUI). Раньше тесты автоматически запускались и работали корректно, но сейчас работают корректно только когда на них смотреть(т.е. они корректно выполняются когда раскрыл окно виртуалки и смотришь на тесты).

Вопрос: 1. Из-за чего такое могло произойти? 
2. Особо информации не нашел, но пишут что можно в Jenkins сделать некоего slave - которые имитируют присутствие человека. (http://r3code.livejournal.com/205024.html) Если кто сталкивался - можете поподробней объяснить.

П.С. какая есть программа/утилита чтобы можно было подсмотреть за виртуалкой, но не считалось что я на нее вошел.

Comment: точно проблема в отсутствии  человека?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, в одних из тестов у меня сохраняются некие файлы. Если я смотрю на прогонку тестов, они autoIt скрипты при мне их сохраняют. И собственно они появляются в некой папке.

Когда я запускаю через Jenkins(или напрямую со своей IDE(IDEA), я на тесты не смотрю, но после прогонки тестов файлы не создаются. 

Повторюсь что раньше Jenkins + AutoIT работали на ура. Просто не понимаю как клики могут зависеть от "присутсвия" человека.

Comment: а в логах нет ошибок о том, что "не смог сохранить данные"?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, я не нашел, да и по идеи он же не выведет эту ошибку, т.к. скрипт заточен на воспроизведение действий(нажатие кнопок), а не определение что он делает.

Comment: Если кто еще зайдет - проблема не решена, но оказалось раньше все это работало потому что я сворачивал не целиком удаленку, а в виде окна(т.е. все окно у меня открыто, но свернуто как окно, а не просто спрятано - коряво объяснил, но надеюсь поймете.)

И вообще это не очень хорошее решение, отсюда вопрос: все таки можно сделать чтобы запускание exe файлов не зависело от "просмотра" на них. И второй вопрос: если нет, то есть некий имитатор смотрящего, и в свернутом окне?

Comment: Касательно удаленки. Еще могу объяснить что в первом случаи при наведении на свернутое окно - действия ретранслируются, при просто свернутом окне - показ обрывается на последнем увиденном "кадре".

Comment: давайте продоллжим общение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71813/questions-771428)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71814/discussion-between-sank-and-senior-pomidor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, на данный момент это решилось переходом с RDP на наблюдалку экрана, в моем случае VNC. Не я делал соединение, поэтому не могу объяснить как производить настройку, но немного понял почему RDP не схватывает экран когда соединение закрыто/ свернуто. 
Оказывается RDP имеется несколько графических пакетов(обработчиков) , я не знаю как точно это работает, но фишка в том что когда мы сворачиваем экран - соединение есть, но картинка с удаленного подключения не обрабатывается, а становится просто черный экран. Соответственно все зависящие программы не понимают как щелкать, куда щелкать и т.д.

Лучше прочитать про обработчики графики в RDP.

В любом случае хотел сказать спасибо за помощь @SeniorPomidor